# SIGINT handler runs only once

Tags: linux, signals, printf

I'm learning about signals and async-signal-unsafe functions. In particular, I learnt that `printf` is async-signal-unsafe and can cause a deadlock when called from the main program thread and from a signal handler. To check this, I wrote the following program (it is a little ugly):

```
/*
 * sig-deadlock.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
sigint_handler(int signum)
{
        int i;
        printf("Signal");
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
        }
}

int
main(void)
{
        int i;
        printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());
        signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
        for (i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
                printf("a");
                sleep(1);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I expect the program to run the inner loop (and hence call `printf`) several times and each time I send a SIGINT (using `kill -INT $PID`) to execute the signal handler, which counts to 30.

On running this, however, I observed that the signal handler runs once and the next signal terminates the process. What causes this behavior and how can I fix this?

OS: Linux 4.9.0.

Comment: I don't know whether or not your test concept would cause a deadlock, when using GNU libc. "Since *locking the same stream twice in the same thread is allowed* the locking objects must be equivalent to recursive mutexes. These mutexes keep track of the owner and the number of times the lock is acquired." Instead it might cause a crash, corrupted output, or completely arbitrary "undefined behaviour" in your program and the actions it performs. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Threads.html#Streams-and-Threads

Answer (score 4):

[`signal(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is part of the old signals API, which isn't always convenient to use, mainly because...

> The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`. The semantics when using `signal()` to establish a signal handler vary across  systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); **do not use it for this purpose.**
>
> In the original UNIX systems, when a handler that was established using `signal()` was invoked by the delivery of a signal, **the disposition of the signal would be reset to `SIG_DFL`**, and the system did not block delivery of further instances of the signal. System V also provides these semantics for `signal()`.
>
> On BSD, when a signal handler is invoked, the signal disposition is not reset, and further instances of the signal are blocked from being delivered while the handler is executing.
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's `signal()` system call provides System V semantics.
> - By default, in glibc 2 and later, the `signal()` wrapper function [...] calls `sigaction(2)` using flags that supply BSD semantics.
> - On glibc 2 and later, if the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature test macro is not defined, then `signal()` provides System V semantics. (The default implicit definition of `_BSD_SOURCE`  is not  provided  if one invokes `gcc(1)` in one of its standard modes (`-std=xxx` or `-ansi`) or... see [`signal(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html).

In other words, there is a myriad of cases in which a handler set with `signal` will not be used more than once: after one signal, the function you defined will be discarded and the handler will be reset to the default, which, for `SIGINT`, is to kill the process.

While I would encourage you to read the man page I just quoted, the best way to handle this situation is probably to stop using `signal` and switch to `sigaction`. The man page will give you all the details you need, but here's a quick sample:

```
void sighandler(int signum);

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&(sa.sa_mask));
    sigaddset(&(sa.sa_mask), SIGINT);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Sleeping...\n");
        sleep(5);
        printf("Woke up!\n");
    }
}

void sighandler(int signum) {
    printf("Signal caught!\n");
}
```

*An important note though:* as you may already know (hence your "infinite" loop in your `main` function), signals will interrupt system calls (such as those `sleep(3)` makes) upon signal reception, whether that signal is handled by the program or not. In my example above, the program *will* print *Woke up!* everytime you `kill` it because it exits the sleep call prematurely. If you have a look at the man page, you'll see the call should return the number of seconds left to sleep when it is interrupted.

Comment: However, this is still wrong.  You shouldn't call `stdio` functions from signal handlers, since they aren't reentrant.

Comment: @SatoKatsura While I would agree if it were the old signals API, note that because `SIGINT` is part of the mask passed to `sigaction`, the handler should never be reentered in the first place. Non-reentrant calls within the handler are therefore not much of an issue ^^

Comment: Consider the following scenario: the user presses Ctrl-C while the program is printing `Sleeping...` or `Woke up!`.  Highly unlikely to happen, and highly unlikely to overflow anything, but still a potential crash.

Answer (score 1):

One more prerequisite that wasn't emphasized here.

You have to set sa_flags in the sigaction structure to ensure consistent results.

```
sa.sa_flags = 0 ; // this works for me
```

> I was tripped up for a good several minutes just now because I had 2 different applications that registered the signal in the same way and only one of them had this issue (catching the signal only once).
>
> After staring at my code for a bit and rereading the man page I realized the different behaviour was because of different nuanced function stack side effects of my 2 applications.
>
> one program registered the signal handler w/ sigaction() super early in main() pretty much before any memory was allocated or any nested functions were entered  (this was the program w/ irregular sigaction behaviour).
>
> The other program called sigaction() after some other variables had been declared at the top of main that took up some memory etc and it seems like by a fluke gave it consistent behaviour to initialize the memory in sa.sa_flags to zero most likely (or some number that probably didn't have the SA_RESETHAND bit set).
>
> The fact that the inconsistent application would sometimes initialize registering the signal w/ catch once behaviour and sometimes w/ catch every time behaviour tipped me off to some kind of randomness that could be caused by garbage among other things.

The quick sample code snippet's convention in John's answer is still incomplete and may give inconsistent results because it omits setting of sa_flags.

Comment: I could use my "powers" to edit John's answer, but even with that in it'll be very much broken because it's using the signal-unsafe `printf()` inside a signal handler and that's a absolutely NO NO EVER, despite appearing on so many examples in forums like this. I'll give it a pass though for the useless `sigaddset` ;-)

Comment: I actually first got excited when including sigemptyset/sigaddset into my code thinking that was the solution because it hinted at the same logic of clearing flags/masks for uninitialized memory. And when it didn't work I squinted at the man page again and at least saw that it was sort of on the right track.